# Триггер, выдающий сообщение...

Tags: sql-server, sql

Помогите, пожалуйста. Не получается создать триггер такой, чтоб выдавал сообщение, допустим, Таблица1 и Таблица2. Сообщение при вводе в Таблицу2, когда значение Поля1 Таблицы1 допустим, < 5. Сообщение, что значение меньше 5, должно выходить в Таблице2. Здесь триггер на какую таблицу на 1 или на 2 надо создавать?! помогите пожалуйста... SQL Server.

Comment: На таблицу 1

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понятно, что нужно :(. Пример триггера с выводом сообщения и откатом действия DML инструкции вызвавшего триггер:

```
CREATE TABLE testT(Val int NULL,RowidV nvarchar(10))
CREATE TABLE testT2(Val int NULL,RowidV nvarchar(10))

create TRIGGER CheckVal_I ON testT
INSTEAD OF INSERT AS 
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE Val < 5)
    BEGIN
      RAISERROR(59998, 16, 1, N'Val less 5')
      RETURN
    END
   insert into testT2(Val,RowidV) select Val,Rowid0 from inserted
   insert into testT(Val,RowidV)  select Val,Rowid0 from inserted
END
```